# Transferring values from specific columns into first empty column

Tags: r, dataframe, readxl

There are many NA's in my dataframe and I need to transfer those cells (at row level) to the left.

I have a dataframe as follows:

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | NA | Xyz | NA | 123 | 123 |
| Cde | NA | NA | Mno | 756 | 888 |
| NA | Pqr | NA | Stu | 0 | 0 |

Expected result as follows:
[image]

How to do that? Is it need loop or there are another solution.

Comment: Do you have a typo in expected for the first row where A3 should be NA?

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` we can use

```
nm1 <- paste0("A", 1:4)
df1[nm1] <- t(apply(df1[nm1], 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
```

Comment: I have try to execute your code, but it is possible to limit columns A1-A4 only not for all columns?